# Get PowerShell to search extension attribute in AD

Tags: powershell, csv, foreach

I'm trying to get PowerShell to import a CSV file that has a list of employee ID numbers and search AD for those numbers.  If I run it the way it is now I get no results, I just get a blank CSV files it creates at the end of the process.

If I tell PowerShell to Write-Host $*.ID it will give me a list of all the IDs that are in the imported CSV.  So it seems that it's able to read the file just fine.  I have also tested and if I replace Get-ADUser -Filter "extensionAttribute13 -like '$*.ID'" with an actual ID number instead of $_.ID I get the result I'm looking for.

I'm not 100% sure what I'm missing in getting the employee numbers passed along to return the data I need.

```
Import-Csv C:\temp\emplid.csv |

ForEach {
    Get-ADUser -Filter "extensionAttribute13 -like '$_.ID'" -Server "dc01" -Properties * | select extensionAttribute13, Name, Description


} | Export-Csv C:\temp\employees.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Any help would be extremely appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put a subexpression $() around $_.ID:

```
Import-Csv C:\temp\emplid.csv |

ForEach {
    Get-ADUser -Filter "extensionAttribute13 -like '$($_.ID)'" -Server "dc01" -Properties * | select extensionAttribute13, Name, Description


} | Export-Csv C:\temp\employees.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked!  Could you please explain what the subexpression does exactly?  I have never used it before.

Comment: A sub-expression is a way of including some PowerShell code within a string and ensuring that the full code executes. By default within a string enclosed in double quotes " " PowerShell will auto replace any $variables with the string contents (or the equivalent of doing a .tostring() method on that variable). This doesn't extend to .properties automatically (in your code it was just assuming .ID was an intended part of the string). By enclosing it in a subexpression you make it interpret .ID as code, not as text.

Comment: Thank you that makes sense now.